# Invalid entity_type specified: customer

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, php-7, adobe-commerce

[image]

sudo php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://vstar.local --db-host=localhost --db-name=vstar --db-user=root --db-password=Root@123 --admin-firstname=alan --admin-lastname=wac --admin-email=alan@webandcrafts.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=INR --timezone=America/Chicago

while creating a table iam getting error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First clear the database and try with this command without sudo

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://vstar.local --db-host=localhost --db-name=vstar --db-user=root --db-password=Root@123 --admin-firstname=alan --admin-lastname=wac --admin-email=alan@webandcrafts.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=INR --timezone=America/Chicago

Comment: still it showing that error

Comment: can you please tell what exactly you're doing?

Comment: I clone a project from git  and set up in my local when i creating my database i getting error
"Invalid entity_type specified: customer" and php version of the project is 7.4 and my composer version is 2.6.6

Comment: okay, now check if you have any third-party extension or not, if you have then you need to create those extensions tables manually because the command which you are entering to install magento database it's only gonna install magento tables not the custom table or custom field which is creating by third-party extensions. or try to get database zip file or something if you can get